# TextInputLayout hintTextSiize is very small

Tags: android, xml, material-design

My problem is that after updating material design dependencies from 1.1.0 to 1.2.1 `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'`
Some TextInputLayout editTexts hint text sizes became very small, even though I'm using same TextInputLayouts with same styles and some of them are fine, some not.

[image]

Code :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/userInfoPasswordTextInputLayout"
                style="@style/TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense.Light"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineEnd"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineStart"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/userInfoFullPhoneNoErrorTextView"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/gray38">

                <com.rj.topsport.utils.view.TopSportTextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/userInfoPasswordEditText"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.Input.Light"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<style name="TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense.Light" parent="TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense.Custom">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/mid_gray</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/mid_gray</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ic_login_input_borders_light_gray</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense.Custom" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@drawable/ic_text_input_selector_transparent</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/login_input_container_height</item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Hint</item>
    <item name="backgroundColor">@null</item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@null</item>
</style>
```

1. I tried to change and put hintTextAppearance everywhere but that didin't changed anything.item
2. Removing hint from editText and putting in textInputLayout didin't changed anything
3. Changing to `1.3.0-beta01` did not helped

EDIT:
thanks to 2 try I investigated the hint string and found that it's because of this `<font size="12">`  `<string name="password"><font size="12">Slaptažodis</font></string>`

Comment: remove the hint of the editText and set it in the `TextInputLayout`

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem This didn't changed anything either

Comment: try updating to `1.3.0-beta01`

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem updating to `1.3.0-beta01` didin't fix it